# Encrypted text field issue in the validation rule

Tags: trigger, validation-rule, debugging, encryption

I have an encrypted text field called Bank_Account__c used in the validation rule with priorvalue as `AND( PRIORVALUE(Bank_Account__c) <> Bank_Account__c , Bank_Account__c <> "")` apart from other criteria. I see this validation rule fires, and is true when ideally it should not be true, when trying to update a record.I put the debug log and see value of Bank_Account__c for that record 
in the trigger context - **newlist or newmap has values as - '*****1234', where as oldlist or oldmap has values as - '567891234'**. Clearly values are changed, and validation rules fires for this record and  validation criteria is true. Similarly , I tried for another record , however in that case - both the new and old values are same and not masked such as  '567891234'.

Any idea , why there could be inconsistent behaviour ? Or could it be a Salesforce bug? I checked the document - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm but it doesn't help either as in both the records debugs are generated in the context of trigger events , so for the first record also , debug logs should have new values as unmasked.

Comment: Hi @ManishAnand, could you please clarify if this is a new record or existing record? Also could you also please clarify the inputs that are failing.
Regarding the trigger: based on the documentation you sent, the data is masked in the apex trigger context.

Comment: @JefersonChaves :- It's for existing record , when trying to update it. I didn't understand your second part of the question. What I am trying to do is , update a field let's say 'X' , because of this validation rule fires which has bank account field where it's check prev value(bank account) <> bank account

Comment: Regarding the trigger: the documentation mentions that fields are encrypted on trigger context, but won't impact validation rules - they work if the field is encrypted or not.